# How can Environment Variable Interpolation for SENTRY_TAGS be achieved with the Sentry Logback Logging Integration in Java Spring Boot?

Tags: java, shell, spring-boot, sentry, spring-logback

When using environment (shell) variables, they are added and sent via the sentry logback integration.

**However, there is a big caveat, they are not interpolated.**

```
SENTRY_DSN=https://xxxxxxxx@sentry.io/xxxxxx
SENTRY_TAGS=app:MyApplication,host:$HOSTNAME,project:${CI_PROJECT_NAME},branch:${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT=${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
```

This happens even if these variables have a value, it will just not get replaced.

Neither `$HOSTNAME` nor `${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}` will be resolved/replaced. It will result in the string just added verbatim and sent to sentry, as can be seen in the screenshot:

[image]

logback-spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

            <appender name="Sentry" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
                <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                    <level>WARN</level>
                </filter>
            </appender>
            <root level="INFO">
                <!-- Log both to console(collected by SumoLogic and Cloudwatch) and Sentry -->
                <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
                <appender-ref ref="Sentry"/>
            </root>

</configuration>
```

This article, explains how to use the logback integration, but there is no mention of SENTRY_TAGS or other variables
https://blog.sentry.io/2016/01/28/capturing-java-exceptions

There is a similar question here: [Setting environment variables of Sentry dynamically for logback.xml Sentry appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59543580/setting-environment-variables-of-sentry-dynamically-for-logback-xml-sentry-appen/59969536#59969536)

Comment: what sentry logback version are you using? I have a similar issue when a pattern that contains a custom conversion rule (a class) is not interpolated either and no warning of that is shown

Comment: Hi, io.sentry:sentry-all:1.7.30 and logback-core-1.2.3

Comment: I don't think that is possible. From what I saw in the Sentry initial config the env properties and the ones from files are read with no transformation. What you could do is to have one file per env and with the properties populated before hand. Hope it helps. Feel free to ask on their github issues page, they will answer quite fast.

Comment: @bogdan.rusu I think that is what our Infrastructure guys did. Parsed the files, populated and then injected them into the environment.